# How to unit test a method of a class which inturn calls a method from another class

Tags: unit-testing, junit, void

Hi my class looks like this.

```
public class Class1 {

    public void method1(Object obj) {

        // Class 2 makes the restApiCall and result as "SUCCESS" if the HTTP response is 202
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        String result = class2.callRestService();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

```
public class Class2 {

    public String callRestService() {
        String url = fetchUrl(System.getProperty(COnstants.URL);
        String result = callRestServiceAPi(url); // Calling the RestApimethod.
        return result;
    }

}
```

I want to write unit test for the class1 and I want to do it by actually not calling RestAPi means I want to mock class2.callRestService() method to return as "success" or "failure". How can it be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `new` (and then don't use *injection*) you'll have always some trouble with test.

You have two alternatives:

1. Use [PowerMockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito)
2. Wrap `new` in a method and mock the method

```
public class Class1 {

    protected Class2 getClient(){
         return new Class2();
    }

    public void method1(Object obj) {

        // Class 2 makes the restApiCall and result as "SUCCESS" if the HTTP response is 202
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        String result = class2.callRestService();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

and then, in your Junit

```
@Test
public void test(){
    Class1 class1 = Mockito.spy(new Class1());
    Class2 class2 = Mockito.mock(Class2.class);
    Mockito.doReturn("your result").when(class2).callRestService();
    Mockito.doReturn(class2).when(class1).getClient();
    // assert something

}
```

More on `Mockito` [here](https://site.mockito.org/)

Comment: Is it not possible without adding that extra method

Comment: As I wrote you can use `PowerMockito` but this is never a good idea, but just last chance